# Modem working, Router working, intermittent internet -- what could cause this?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, internet-connection

I'm having issues with intermittent internet in my apartment, and am trying to resolve what the issue could be.

My modem is operational, and has an indicator light for being connected to the internet.  It's a DOCSIS 3.0 16x16 modem (Surfboard 6183), so as far as I can tell, this isn't the issue.

My wifi router is similarly working; I can see the network on my devices, and the indicator light on the router shows that it's connected to the internet.

However, randomly when I'm connected to the internet, my connection will disappear and my devices show "No Internet" in their network menus.  But when the devices manage to connect (which can be for 5-60 minutes at a time), I can do a speedtest and have download speeds upwards of 200 Mbps.

I'm also seeing this on a variety of devices (phone, laptop, tablet) running a variety of operating systems (Android, OSX, Windows), so I don't believe that it's a network configuration issue.

My guess is that it's an issue with either the ISP or the infrastructure in the building, but I'm not sure what other tests I can run to narrow down where the issue may lie (and get useful help).

The intermittent nature of the problem makes it difficult to call my ISP, as they could just show up and it will have 'fixed' itself, which is why I'm trying to narrow down the causes as much as possible before filing a ticket.

thanks!

Comment: What's does the surfboard modem report for upstream/downstream SNR?

Comment: All 16 downstream channels are within parameters; Power is between -2.0 and 0.0 dBmV while SNR is between 40.0 and 45.0 dBmV for each channel.  Similarly, upstream power is at 47.5 dBmV, which seems right per the SB6183 User Manual.

Comment: What's the log look like? You getting any "T" based errors? Critical or severe warnings? Who is the ISP? For Docsis networks in our area, 47.5DB for upstream is not really acceptable, it's at the upper limit before failure.